# Editing throws error : Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
protected void schgrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                //getting username from particular row
                string schlName = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "schlName"));
                //identifying the control in gridview
                ImageButton lnkbtnresult = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("imgbtnDelete");
                //raising javascript confirmationbox whenver user clicks on link button
                lnkbtnresult.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return ConfirmationBox('" + schlName + "')");
            }
}
```

Here comes the error at above line :

> *Object Reference not set to an instance of an object*

```
protected void schgrid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
        schgrid.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

        if (txtSearch.Text == "")
        {
            BindSchoolDetails();
        }
        else
        {
            BindSearchDetails();
        }
    }
```

Whenever I use `rowEditing`, the exception is thrown in `schgrid_RowDataBound` which is actually used for deleting gridview records.

Please help me resolve this problem. Show me some code to correct the issue

Comment: enable `exception handling` in VS and VS will hit your code on ***exact** line where exception happens.

Comment: lnkbtnresult.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return ConfirmationBox('" + schlName + "')")
Here comes the error..

Comment: rick: so I would *suppose* that `lnkbtnresult` is `Null`

Comment: Whenever i use "rowEditing" error is thrown in "schgrid_RowDataBound" which is actually used for deleting gridview records.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I think, your **lnkbtnresult** must be null, you can check its value while debugging before hitting the error line. That Image button might be null because of wrong name( string 'schlName') provided to DataBinder.Eval.
Just try to check if correct Id you have used for schlName.
Put your aspx code as well, would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If lnkbtnresult is null it is likely because the control is not called imgbtnDelete.